# Count occurrences of items in 2 data frames and then checking to compare 2 dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to take 2 data frames, see if there are occurrences of 2 columns in one, and then compare and see if those happened on the same day so an example of the data would be:

```
df1:
user   Last_used
user1  10-7-2017
user2  10-20-2018
user3  1-12-2015

df2:
user  occurence
user1 10-7-2017
user1 10-7-2017
user2 10-10-2017
user2 10-20-2018
user3 1-12-2015
user3 09-14-2016
```

My results would then be:

```
df1
user    Last_used   occurrences_that_day
user1   10-7-2017   2
user2   10-20-2018  1
user3   1-12-2015   1
```

I know that i can use map do do this with 1 of the values, but if i try to map last used and occurrence and there are multiples on this date it will show even when the user id is differet

One thing I should also should note is that my dataframes both have rows of over 150k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `merge` with `groupby` `agg`

```
df1.merge(df2,left_on=['user','Last_used'],right_on=['user','occurence']).groupby('user').occurence.agg(['count','last'])
Out[129]: 
       count        last
user                    
user1      2   10-7-2017
user2      1  10-20-2018
user3      1   1-12-2015
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, when i do this i get the error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'occurence'

Am I missing something? I tried replacing "occurrence" with my actual date field and it didnt work

Comment: @SamL check you df2 columns names

Comment: how can i do this and keep all the additional columns from df1? for instance in my df1 it also has user information such as name and location

Comment: @SamL what I will do is merge it back for df1, after my code you get , Newdf.reset_index().merge(df1.drop_duplicates('user'),on='user')